# Should we also use those migrations which they are only for changing the data in the database in our testing?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, migration, functional-testing

We have a bunch of migrations (200+) which most of them are there to change the data in the database and that affect our testing. For example we have a migration like this one

```
 public function up()
    {
        $deleteId = DB::table('lookups')
            ->where('code', '=', 'VI')
            ->where('type', '=', 'country')
            ->where('value', '=', 'U.S. Virgin Islands')
            ->first(['id'])->id;

           DB::table('lookups')
                ->where('id', '=', $deleteId ?? 0)
                ->update(['deleted_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeLocalString()]);
    }
```

As you can see this will throw an error if we run it in the testing env. because the record does not exists in the testing environment. (we are using faker for that purpose). and my question is, should we some how skip this kind of migrations or what is the best solution?

Comment: You can do it in one query, then it doesn't throw.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I am going to make a few assumptions in my answer so please review them and let me know if any are incorrect.

1. You are part of the development team.
2. In the customer environment if the record doesn't exist at the time the migration is run then that is an error in the environment.
3. You are not explicitly testing this migration in this test.

Ok, so first of all there are a few alarm bells going off in my head. Essentially you are saying that your test environment does not match the customer environment. This, of course, is not necessarily a problem, but do make sure that your test environment is sufficiently representative of the customer environment for the tests to be meaningful.

In an ideal situation I would avoid the error by ensuring that your fake environment has the record required by the migration. This way you also exercise the migration as it runs.

Are you providing a fake database e.g. an in memory database for the tests? If so, simply add the record when the database starts up so that the migration can be run.

Are you mocking the calls to the database? If so, have you tried mocking the call to this function and essentially make it a no-op?